# Add button at Vaadin grid header

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

How to add button at grid header without make another column in Vaadin Grid?
please see this Vaadin sample 
http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features
I want to add another button to header
[image]

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible, but if you can explain what you're trying to achieve, functionality-wise, perhaps we can come with alternative solutions.

Comment: I want to add control button to show or hide the filter input text , and i think is the best place to add the button is besides columns hideable button

Comment: @RoylistoPutraPradana So, you want to hide filter input text row, or just the component?